# output with condition based sub query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, conditional-statements, inner-query

Below is my query:

**select c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 from table1 where c1 =0** //Condition 1
**AND c2="abc"** //Condition 2
**AND c3="xxx"** //Condition 3
**AND c4 = 5** //Condition 4

Here as we know that condition 2 will be applied on result data given by condition 1, condition 3 will be applied on on result data given by condition 2 and 1 and similarly condition 4 will be applied...

I want query which will execute further if any condition in between fails. 
 
 Means if **condition 3** will give no result (or null result set) then my **condition 4** will be applied on null result set so defiantly final output will be null, but I want if **condition 3** will give no result (or null result set) then **condition 4** "Should be Applied" to result set return by **condition 2 and 1**.

Here I can not change sequence of conditions due to performance issue.

Please guide me with query.

Comment: I think sample data and desired would be a big help in understanding what you are trying to do.  Your explanation is also incorrect:  SQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions.  The result set simply guarantees that the `where` clause evaluates to true.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i am dealing with table having crores of rows, so i am not able to give you sample data also by AND condition i am minimizing my data.but i hope you understand my question. Is there any other way get desire output from this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got one simple solution for this and it is working in my scenario. Also I am able to reduce time for query execution on my big data. Defiantly two queries will be executed but i find this proper solution.

I used simple Union query.

**select c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 from table1 where c1 =0** //Condition 1
**AND c2="abc"** //Condition 2
**AND c3="xxx"** //Condition 3
**AND c4 = 5** //Condition 4
**UNION**
**select c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 from table1 where c1 =0** //Condition 1
**AND c2="abc"** //Condition 2
**AND c4 = 5** //Condition 4

If someone else has more accurate and proper solution. Please post it.

Comment: `Union` the way you wrote it would just yield `Distinct` of the second part alone.

Comment: @Y.B. can you please explain with any example. Problem which i was facing is getting resolved by UNION as of now. I really appreciate if you can get me better solution.

Comment: **Condition 3** is missing from second part of your `UNION`. Thus second part of the `UNION` would take all the rows selected in first part _and also_ those rows that do not satisfy just **Condition 3**. `UNION` without `ALL` would return `DISTINCT` list of records from both parts. Since first part is a subset of second part the `UNION` is equivalent to `DISTINCT` of second part.

Comment: Try it: `With table1 As (
 Select *
 From (
  Values
   ((0), ('abc'), ('xxx'), (5), (1)),
   ((0), ('abc'), ('yyy'), (5), (2)),
   ((0), ('abc'), ('xxx'), (6), (3))
  ) As a (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)
)
Select c1, c2, c3, c4, c5
From table1
Where c1 =0  --Condition 1
AND c2='abc' --Condition 2
AND c3='xxx' --Condition 3
AND c4 = 5   --Condition 4
UNION
Select c1, c2, c3, c4, c5
From table1
Where c1 =0  --Condition 1
AND c2='abc' --Condition 2
AND c4 = 5   --Condition 4`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 from table1 where (c1 =0) or (c2="abc") or (c3="xxx") or (c4 = 5)
```

Comment: Here I am dealing with table having crores of rows, so by AND condition i am minimizing my data, so if I use OR it will create performance issue as query will take so much time to get execute...

Comment: @Karthika: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you want to have **condition 3** optional. That can be done, but would hardly be an efficient solution:

```
Select c1, c2, c3, c4, c5
From table1
Where c1 = 0
  AND c2 = "abc"
  AND (c3 = "xxx"
       OR NOT Exists (Select '*' From table1 Where c1 = 0 AND c2 = "abc" AND c3 = "xxx")
      )
  AND c4 = 5
```

Better approach might be to use temporary table filtered on conditions 1 and 2 with further logic applied to this data subset.

Comment: your solution is looking feasible but yes you are right... query is taking so much time to get execute.